# use gdb to debug static libraries

Tags: debugging, gdb, g++, static-libraries

I tried to debug my c++ program which includes a third party library(openMVS) with gdb. The library is included as static library (.a file). The problem is gdb can't step into the function body of the library. Instead, gdb steps over the line. Specifically, I want gdb to step into the line "scene. densereconstruction()" where scene is an object defined by the library and densereconstruction() is an function of that class, but gdb just stepped over the line. Meanwhile, gdb couldn't find the source file when I tried to set a break point to the file containing the function densereconstruction().

The library is installed in /usr/local. I can find the corresponding .a(static library) file. I built both the library and my own program with parameter set to -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Debug.

I don't have too much experience debugging in gdb. Thank you all for the help in advanced.

Comment: If you have compiler optimizations enabled the debugger will not show a "logical" code path, it will show the optimized one. Compile the program with `-g -Og` to both enable debugging symbols and make tracing easier.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The CMakeLists.txt does have the line "set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")". I think that will add "-g -0g" in the resulting Makefile? Is that correct?

Comment: Check by running `make VERBOSE=1`